# restful authentication and LDAP

Tags: ruby, authentication, ldap, restful-authentication

I'm new on ruby, i use the restful authentication plugin and that works perfectly, Now, i have an authentication based on LDAP, and i want to combine ldap and restful authentication.
Ldap also

Any examples ?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

authlogic is preferred by many over restful_authentication (there are plenty of comparisons around), and a cursory search yields http://lbi.lostboys.nl/prikbord/ruby-on-rails-ldap-integration. I have not attempted it myself by it may be a starter.